# HOw to use local instance of TPrinter

Tags: delphi, printing

I need to do some printing using TPrinter. The problem is I can not, for various reasons, use Global object Printer.

I want to be able to create my instance of TPrinter and print using that one.

I tried with:

```
MyPrinter := TPrinter.Create;
MyPrinter.BeginDoc;
```

but this generates AV.

Any idea what does it take to print something using my instance of TPrinter?

Regards
Goran Nagy

Comment: Why can't you use the global Printer? Are you printing multiple things at the same time to different printers?

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the soucre for printers, the AbortProc uses the global FPrinter object.
You can solve this by call Printer function before caling TPrinter.Create, then it dosn't generate a AccessViolation.
It will posibly solve your problem, but MyPrinter.Abort wil NOT propoply not work correcty.

Telling why you can't use the global object, gives other users a posibility to suggest alternative solutions.

Answer (score 1):

The `TPrinter` object is not really designed to be created locally, but instead is designed to be used from the 'singleton' function `Printer` in the `Printers` unit. Generally you would use that.

From the help:

> Use TPrinter to manage any printing performed by an application. Obtain an instance of TPrinter by calling the Printer function in the Printers unit.

**Edit**: Actually, having had a think you could do something like this:

```
procedure PrintThings;
var
  LMyPrinter: TPrinter;
  LOldPrinter: TPrinter;
begin
  LMyPrinter := TPrinter.Create;
  try
    LOldPrinter := SetPrinter(LMyPrinter);
    try

      // your printing code goes here

    finally
      SetPrinter(LOldPrinter);
    end;
  finally
    LMyPrinter.Free;
  end;
end;
```